# How to change the color of button and pause screen for few second when it clicked?

Tags: android, button, handler

I am working on android quiz .I wanted to add button. when i click on it change Image or color and holds button for a while to check the answer and If the answer is correct then it show Green Color and wrong red color.

I have Implemented in Change of Color on button like this at the end but i don't understand how to implement Handler to delay :-

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);
        processSession();

    }
    private void processSession(){
                /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
        nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }


    /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));


        int score = currentGame.getScore();
        String scr = String.valueOf(score);
        TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        score1.setText(scr);
      try{ 
         new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView timers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
                timers.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() { 
                currentGame.decrementScore();
                processSession();
                   }
         }.start();
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          throw new RuntimeException(ex);
      }
        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.answer5)
        {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Are you sure?").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                finish();
                 }
             }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

                }

        else
        {

            if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
          }
        }
      }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {
     try {
     final Button b=(Button) v;
     final String answer = b.getText().toString();
     counterTimer.cancel();
     b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans);
     b.setEnabled(false);

     //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");


         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 if( (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer)))
                {
                    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansgreen);
                    //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
                    currentGame.incrementScore();
                }
                else{
                    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansred);
                    //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
                    currentGame.decrementScore1();
                }
           }
         }, 10000000);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
     return true;
}
```

Any answer is appreciable.

Thank's in advance

Comment: NPE at QuestionActivity.java 121 ? what is this line 121 bro ?

Comment: @twntee its just getting the Question from database on the on Image button.

Comment: that point is returning null, i guess the above code works well.

Comment: @twntee its working fine before using the handler when u help me on change of the Image .I am not getting what i have done wrong.

Comment: seems like an error in try block :/

Comment: @twntee but it's working fine .

Comment: then, I will be only able to help you after I test it, it will take two days.

Comment: ok!! sure I will waiting for your answer.

Comment: @twntee i am still waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Implemented this code on button to change the color on button.Hope it work for you.

```
  private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {

            Button b=(Button) v;
            String answer = b.getText().toString();

            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans);

                 b.setEnabled(false);

                if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
                {
                    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansgreen);
                }
                else{
                    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansred);
                }
                return true;
            }
```

**Handler**

```
if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            final Handler handle = new Handler();
            Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, EndgameActivity.class));
                }
            };
            handle.postDelayed(delay,1000);
        }
        else
        {
            final Handler handle = new Handler();
            Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class));
                }
            };
            handle.postDelayed(delay,1000);
                  }
              }
```

Comment: yeah it work's but can u tell me how to work on Delay.Great for reply.

Comment: why don't you implement handler onclick of button.

Comment: how can i do that.can help me with some example.

Answer (score 3):

We can do something like this :

```
final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
int delaySeconds = 1;

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // return true on correct & false on incorrect 
                    if (answerTrue())
                        // change the background to green.
                        imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                    else
                        // change the background to red.
                        imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                }
            }, delaySeconds * 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wow Great It work's for me.it changes my color of the button.but i can't hold it for sometime it change as i clicked on the button.

Comment: @ChandanKumar try after removing the line `imageButton.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: it's same as before .It change color for instance and goes to new ques.

Comment: @ChandanKumar in the onclick use a new handler and delay the color change for few seconds.. wait I edit the code

Comment: @ChandanKumar please try the edited code, I am not on my device, so tell me if it works.

Comment: i have Implemented this code but it doesn't work for me. After editing ,my application stop working .I just updated my code.kindly, tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: @ChandanKumar please paste the logcat why it stopped and i will help you till i can don't worry.

Comment: I just uploaded my logcat.can u tell me where i am creating a mistake.

Comment: You help me out change of button color .so u have some Great Skill.but i am looking for other half answer.Stay in touch, I have to ask more query.

Comment: @ChandanKumar yes okay.

Comment: i am still waiting for your positive response .how to use handler in the above code.plz guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Handler` to **delay** certain actions.

```
Handler h = new Handler();

 h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
         // DO DELAYED STUFF
     }
 }, delaytime); // e.g. 3000 milliseconds
```

> The actions you take inside the `run()` method will be **executed after
>   the delay-time** you set.

Comment: can u help how to use handler in the above code at checkAnswer(View view). i am really stuck in using this handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal via `Handler` and posting it to `UIThread`

```
Imagebutton ib= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.YourImageButtonId); //Imagebutton default may be something different.
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
Handler h = new Handler();
 h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
     //Put your conditions accordingly
     ib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Green);     
    }
 }, delaytime); // e.g. 3000 milliseconds
});
```

Comment: I am looking for the solution of this problem can u help me out how to solve it .

Comment: can u help me,how to use handler to delay click on button in my edited code.waiting for some positive respond from you.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html
You will need two threads try(){blah blah}catch.
 wait() the first till second notifies it it has answer setBackgroundColor on button

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your manifest what is up with the package name? see the Null pointer exception in logcat? Is it really com.xxx.xxx? Are you calling a resource that is null? A try{ check the answer ...}catch ... so spawn a new thread while you change color.

Comment: i am not able to delay on my button after press and there is no error in my logcat now.so i just trying to implement handler on CheckAnswer()so that my question delay for some moment.